# Org mode: #+INCLUDE remote files?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I regularly use Org mode's `#+INCLUDE` command to include local files in my Org file. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to include remote files (i.e. files that I reference via a URL) into my main Org file so that the source code gets embedded when I export.

My current specific use case would be to add a raw code snippet from a local Gitlab instance to an Org file. I have tried the following:

```
#+INCLUDE: "https://url-to-gitlab/snippets/11/raw" src sh
```

but that gives me the following error message when exporting from Org to PDF:

> org-export-expand-include-keyword: Cannot include file /home/ph0t0nix/Org_files/https:/url_to_gitlab/snippets/11/raw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not an org user.

The `#+INCLUDE` command requires valid file names in Emacs. If you want to include a remote file, you better use Tramp file names.

However, if you enable URL Handler Mode (apply `(url-handler-mode 1)` ), your `#+INCLUDE` command shall work.

Comment: Thanks Michael! That worked perfectly.